# How to prevent inline functions from binding to old state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In a project with React components using hooks, I am trying to understand how to properly avoid calling callbacks that are bound to old state values. The below example illustrates the issue (but is not the code I am working on).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Message = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  function doStuff() {
    console.log(message);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(doStuff, 1000)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={message}
        placeholder="Enter a message"
        onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <p>
        <strong>{message}</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```

The problem here is of course that `setInterval` will keep the `doStuff` function as it was when the effect was called the first (and only time). And at that time the `message` state was empty and hence, the interval function will print an empty string every second instead of the message that is actually inside the text box.

In my real code, I am having external events that should trigger function calls inside the component, and they suffer this same issue.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `useCallback` and pass it as a dependency to your effect.

```
const doStuff = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(message);
}, [message]);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(doStuff, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval); // clean up
}, [doStuff]);
```

Here when `message` gets updated it will have its new value in the `doStuff`

Comment: A caveat though, this is essentially the same as clearing the interval on every update of message. So if you update the message too often, the interval wont fire.

Comment: My actual code does not contain an interval, I just picked that to get the smallest possible example. I will look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in it's own hook also. I have this in my production code

```
/**
 * A react hook for setting up an interval
 * @param handler - Function to execute on interval
 * @param interval - interval in milliseconds
 * @param runImmediate - If the function is executed immediately
 */
export const useInterval = (handler: THandlerFn, interval: number | null, runImmediate = false): void => {
  const callbackFn = useRef<THandlerFn>()

  // Update callback function
  useEffect((): void => {
    callbackFn.current = handler
  }, [handler])

  // Setup interval
  useEffect((): (() => void) | void => {
    const tick = (): void => {
      callbackFn.current && callbackFn.current()
    }

    let timerId: number
    if (interval) {
      if (runImmediate) {
        setTimeout(tick, 0)
      }

      timerId = setInterval(tick, interval)

      return (): void => {
        clearInterval(timerId)
      }
    }
  }, [interval, runImmediate])
}
```