# How to avert inline functions from binding to old state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm implementing this in reactjs and now stucked here. Thanks in advance. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **useCallback** and pass it as a dependency to your effect.

For your reference check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589158/how-to-prevent-inline-functions-from-binding-to-old-state-values)